# Populate one Dropdown on change of another dropdown using jQuery from database

Tags: jquery, json, drop-down-menu

I am newbie in Java Servlets. I have 2 dropdowns, say A and B, and I have this situation where if dropdown A changes, without reloading the page, dropdown B fills or populates data from the database.

I have seen a solution here in which it is said that this can be done by using jQuery. This is URL for doing this
[How to generate dynamic drop down lists using jQuery and jsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896730/how-to-generate-dynamic-drop-down-lists-using-jquery-and-jsp)

I wrote a json string on the response stream but when I check the values returned from it by using `alert(options);` it is returning `null`.
but when it write response.getWriter().write(json);json has got values not empty
I don't know what to do.

Comment: Post your code, or an example, or the site page where it happens. We can't help you with no code

Comment: possible duplicate of [populate dropdown on selection of other dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343209/populate-dropdown-on-selection-of-other-dropdown)

Comment: @Diodeus this seems to be a very specific js error, let him show us his code..

Answer (score 2):

```
function CallBack(data) {
        var obj = data;
        var id = "";
        var value = "";
        $.each(data,
            function (index, item) {
                id = item.Id;
                value = item.Value;
                $('#ProductId')
               .append($("<option></option>")
               .attr("value", id)
               .text(value));
            }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure about your code but you can do something like :

```
$('#drop_down_1_id').change(function(){
var drop_down_1_value = $(this).options[$('#drop_down_1_id').selectedIndex];
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url : 'url',
  data : 'value='+drop_down_1_value,
  dataType : 'json',
  success: function(data){
    $('#drop_down_2_id').html('');
    $(data).each(function(value){
      $('#drop_down_2_id').append('<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>');
    }); // you can change this loop as per your response data type
  }
});
});
```

Comment: yes i understand this but when i use this is giving me error i am not understanding what to do iam using netbeans IDE is some brases missing giving me syntax error

Comment: yeah there were some comma missing. i fixed it