# Get Values of Dropdown based on First Dropdown selected

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

**PHP/MYSQL**

```
<div style="width:810px; margin:inherit; padding-left:170px;">
    <select style="width:300px;" id="n" name="userListingCateory">

        <option  disabled="disabled">Category...</option>
        <?php while($row = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {echo "<option value=". $row['catID'] . ">" .$row['catName']."</option>";}
        unset($sth2);
        ?>
    </select> 
    <select style="width:340px;" id="n" name="userListingSubCateory">
        <option  disabled="disabled">Sub-Category...</option>
        <?php while($row = $sth3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {echo "<option value=". $row['scatID'] . ">" .$row['scatName']."</option>";}
        unset($sth3);
        ?>
    </div>
</select>
```

This HTML above gets all categories and sub-categories in two tables `[Category]` and `[SubCategory]`

The php/mysql that needs to run upon clicking the `[Category]` dropdown would look like:

```
SELECT scatID, scatName 
FROM Category C, SubCategory SC
WHERE C.catID = SC.catID
AND C.catID = $origCatIDSelected;
```

How do I get this to get the `sub-categories` based on which `category` is chosen?

Is there any easy way to implement in jquery/php?

Thanks

Comment: You need this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7137507/762449

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize the [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler that executes an [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/ajax/) function to pass the current selected category to a PHP file containing the code to query your database and then return the updated output to the client side via the success callback that is built into the [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/ajax/) function within jQuery.

Also, you should avoid using the same ID for multiple objects as the ID attribute is meant to be unique.

Comment: Can you show me how to implement this change event ? The whole point of the catID in both tables is for joins :)