# List Provinces in dropdown based upon Country dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I need some assistance with this javascript/jquery script.
I have a page where every Region/Province/State is a MySQL table called `States`
Organization:

[image: Table Layout]

There is a dropdown menu called Province, that has all these regions in it.

I'm trying to make it so that when a user selects a country from the dropdown menu:

```
<select add_other="" multiplyable="true" class="form_input_select" name="Country[]">
```

The Province drop-down menu below it runs a query to show all States/Provinces that belong to the Country selected and filters/strips out the others that don't.

```
<select add_other="" multiplyable="true" class="form_input_select" name="Province[]">
<option value="204">Alsace</option>
<option value="239">Aquitaine</option>
<option value="271">Auvergne</option>
```

I've read and looked around and apparently the only effective way to do this with Javascript/JSON to use it with PHP as you can only use node.js to connect to a MySQL database.
I'm fairly new to Javascript and really need some pointing in the right direction to put this together as most of the scripts I've found around are really specific to their needs for their site.
I'm doing this on Boonex Dolphin so not much modifying the hardcoded HTML itself, which is why I have to take the Javascript/Jquery route with this.

Comment: there's plenty of chained-dropdown examples on this site. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815453/get-values-of-dropdown-based-on-first-dropdown-selected?rq=1

Comment: I do, many of those i find hard to customize for me, because it's suited for their type of task at hand.

Comment: doesn't matter. you need to learn the concept. after that the rest is just details.