# Loading values from database to JavaScript in a select Tag

Tags: javascript, database, select, onchange

I'm new to JavaScript. my problem is, i have 3 select html tags. one for country, next for State and the last one is for city. i have different tables like countries,states,cities. the problem is when l click the particular country, the corresponding states would be loaded using onchange event in java script.after loading it i need to click the state then the corresponding cities should load.

but i don't know the coding. if any one have it please send me. its urgent. my boss is waiting for my result.

Comment: I doubt anyone will code that up for you as you have many variables in this question. You've got everything stored in a database (what database?). You will need to onchange() query the database through ajax to then fill the next select or cascading dropdown in line. There's a lot more than "urgent" requires.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a site where you can get work done from others. You need to put in time and effort and only when you do get stuck without any answers available should you post your questions here. I'm downmarking your question for this reason.

Answer (score 2):

If you just search the internet you would get lots of solutions from which you can choose depending on the server side technology you use. Here is one using ASP.Net and JQuery

http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/80/posts/10655/cascading-drop-down-examplecountry-state-and-city-in-jquery.aspx

StackOverflow is not a site where you can get work done from others. You need to put in time and effort and only when you do get stuck without any answers available should you post your questions here. I'm downmarking your question for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to look into AJAX. What you're trying to accomplish is exceedingly common. There are heaps of examples if you do a quick google search for [cascading dropdowns](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=cascading+dropdown+ajax).

Since you'll be dealing with AJAX, I suggest you start out with a library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), as building for browser compatibility is a time consuming task without it.

To get you started, you would need a basic structure like the following:

```
$('#my-select').change(function() {
   // code that will be evaluated when #my-select changes
});
```

From there, you would initiate an AJAX request roughly like so:

```
var country = $('#my-select').val();
$.post('/get-states', { country: country }, function(res) {
   // code that will be evaluated when the ajax request completes
});
```

In the callback above, you would populate the child dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

If i did understand correctly, what you want to do is AJAX.

when the onchange event happens, the javascript code sends a request to a server's PHP(or any other server scripts) that process the requests, and sends back the data to the javascript that process the data and outputs to the user.

I don't know the code myself from the top of my head, but i can recommend that you look at [Jquery](http://jquery.com/) and its plugins, there you will surely find the code you want, and quickly assemble the whole process..

**EDIT:** and i just found your answer thanks to the other answer : [Cascade Dropdown List using jQuery/PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137357/cascade-dropdown-list-using-jquery-php)

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
var states = new Array();

states['Canada'] = new Array('Alberta','British Columbia','Ontario');
states['Mexico'] = new Array('Baja California','Chihuahua','Jalisco');
states['United States'] = new Array('California','Florida','New York');


// City lists
var cities = new Array();

cities['Canada'] = new Array();
cities['Canada']['Alberta']          = new Array('Edmonton','Calgary');
cities['Canada']['British Columbia'] = new Array('Victoria','Vancouver');
cities['Canada']['Ontario']          = new Array('Toronto','Hamilton');

cities['Mexico'] = new Array();
cities['Mexico']['Baja California'] = new Array('Tijauna','Mexicali');
cities['Mexico']['Chihuahua']       = new Array('Ciudad Juárez','Chihuahua');
cities['Mexico']['Jalisco']         = new Array('Guadalajara','Chapala');

cities['United States'] = new Array();
cities['United States']['California'] = new Array('Los Angeles','San Francisco');
cities['United States']['Florida']    = new Array('Miami','Orlando');
cities['United States']['New York']   = new Array('Buffalo','new York');


function setStates() {
  cntrySel = document.getElementById('country');
  stateList = states[cntrySel.value];
  changeSelect('state', stateList, stateList);
  setCities();
}

function setCities() {
  cntrySel = document.getElementById('country');
  stateSel = document.getElementById('state');
  cityList = cities[cntrySel.value][stateSel.value];
  changeSelect('city', cityList, cityList);
}

function changeSelect(fieldID, newOptions, newValues) {
  selectField = document.getElementById(fieldID);
  selectField.options.length = 0;
  for (i=0; i<newOptions.length; i++) {
    selectField.options[selectField.length] = new Option(newOptions[i], newValues[i]);
  }
}

// Multiple onload function created by: Simon Willison
// http://simonwillison.net/2004/May/26/addLoadEvent/
function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

addLoadEvent(function() {
  setStates();
});
```

HTML:

```
<fieldset style="width: 230px;">
<legend><strong>Make your selection</strong></legend>
<p>
<form name="test" method="POST" action="processingpage.php">
<table>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">Country:</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">
<select name="country" id="country" onchange="setStates();">
  <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
  <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
  <option value="United States">United States</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">State:</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">
<select name="state" id="state" onchange="setCities();">
  <option value="">Please select a Country</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td style="text-align: left;">City:</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">
<select name="city"  id="city">
  <option value="">Please select a Country</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</fieldset>
```

It took me 5 seconds to google and paste it. Plz do some research before posting.

original source: http://www.javascriptsource.com/forms/country-state-city-drop-down-list.html