# Auto-change drop down menu, html

Tags: php, html

I have to 2 drop down menu which look like this :

[a drop down http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/3786/90550627.jpg](http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/3786/90550627.jpg)

The Item menu have two value which is "Server" and "Switch". Meanwhile, the value in Model menu depend on the value in the Item menu. The value in Model menu is called from the database. What I want to do is when "Server" is selected, it will call data from server table into the Model menu and when "Switch" is selected, it will call data from switch table. How can I do that?

Comment: just like country city dropdowns case??

Comment: What you need is javascript or if you have no backgrounds using native JS u can use js libraries like jQUery. much easy to learn.

Comment: some links that can help http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/02/23/populate-a-select-dropdown-list-using-jquery-and-ajax/

Answer (score 2):

Lets take an easy example, I'm using this for the same purpose that you want and it works perfectly fine.

***I'm using this for populating city dropdown according to selection in country dropdown, HERE YOU CAN TAKE COUNTRY AS ITEM AND CITY AS MODEL***

This is the country dropdown:

```
<?php
        $countrylist=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM country ORDER BY name ASC");
        echo "<select name='country' id='country' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\" title='Country e:g; United Kingdom,Pakistan'><option value='0'>Select Country</option>";
        while($clist=mysql_fetch_array($countrylist))
        {
          echo "<option value='$clist[Name]'>$clist[Name]</option>"."<br/>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
 ?>
```

This is the region dropdown:

```
<select name="region" id="region" ></select>
```

Now make a seperate file named crlist.js and include it in the page having above code like this:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="crlist.js"> </script>
```

code for crlist.js:

```
var request = false;
/*@cc_on @*/
/*@if (@_jscript_version >= 5)
try {
request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
} catch (e) {
try {
request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} catch (e2) {
request = false;
}
}
@end @*/
function fillSelect(country,path) {
var url = path+"crlist.php?country=" + country;
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.onreadystatechange = go;
request.send(null);
}

function go() {
if (request.readyState == 4) {
//if (request.status == 200) {

var response = request.responseText;

var list=document.getElementById("region");
            for (i = list.length - 1; i>=0; i--) {
                list.remove(i);
            }
var records=response.split('|');
for (i=1; i<records.length; i++) {
    //alert("rcord="+records[i]);
    var record=records[i].split('*');
    var region=record[0];
    //alert("region="+region);
    var regionid=record[1];
    //alert("regionid="+regionid);
    var x=document.createElement('option');
    //var y=document.createTextNode(region);
    x.text=region;
    //x.value=region;
    //alert(x.text);
   //x.appendChild(y);
   //list.appendChild(x);
   list.options.add(x);
   }
  //}
 }
}

function initCs(path) {

if (!request && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
var country=document.getElementById('country');
    country.onchange=function() {

        if(this.value!="Select") {

            var list=document.getElementById("region");
            for (i = list.length - 1; i>=0; i--) {
                list.remove(i);
            }
        //while (list.childNodes[0]) {
        //list.removeChild(list.childNodes[0]);
        //}
        }
        fillSelect(this.value,path);
        //alert(this.value);

    }
//fillSelect(country.value);
}
```

Now make a seperate file named crlist.php.

Code for crlist.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'yourconfigfile.php';

$cname = $_GET['country'];

$query="select ID,Name from city where CountryCode=(select code from country where name='$cname') Order By Name ASC";
$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($region = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    echo "<option value='".$region['Name']."'>".$region['Name']."</option>";
}       
?>
```

Now add following script on the page having dropdowns:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="crlist.js"> </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    initCs("");

});
</script>
```

This is my own script, and i've assumed that you have created country and region tables. But you need to tweak the queries and above code according to your db structure.

Reference to my answer: [Cascade Dropdown List using jQuery/PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137357/cascade-dropdown-list-using-jquery-php/7137507#7137507)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why not use jquery ajax functions instead of going through all those hassle? Just a food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an ajax call to update the select box.

JavaScript function on Item select box to call ajax.

For your reference : http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/

Comment: Update the link in answer. You can use it now.