# Auto populate two drop down menus

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

There are two Drop down menus, 
A and B.

The values in A are:- Car, Bike, Plane
The values in B are (when car is selected):- ferari, mercedes
When Bike is selected:- Ducati, harley
when plane is selected:- MIG, Concorde

Also after the Value from both the Drop menus are selected, a text box with the price will be updated, and i need this to be a recurring process. How do i implement it? I am fairly new to PHP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cascade Dropdown List using jQuery/PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137357/cascade-dropdown-list-using-jquery-php)

Comment: i think you want to make dynamic select box, follow the link: http://blog.webtech11.com/2012/03/04/dynamic-select-box-with-php-and-jquery.html

Comment: if you dont want the site to refresh everytime use javascript, else i refer to http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: i haven't got anything started as yet, i am completely jumbled up at the moment. 

@jogesh_p i don't know how to integrate j query and php. Please could you give a little more description on how to achieve that.

Comment: @jogesh_p i have tried using your code but i think i am messing up somewhere. Please could you help out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would like to thank jogesh_p for his help.

I have finally managed to auto populate both the drop down menus, and made the 2nd drop down menu dependent on the 1st drop down menu.

As jogesh mentioned his blog at [Dynamic select box with php and jQuery](http://blog.webtech11.com/2012/03/04/dynamic-select-box-with-php-and-jquery.html)

did help a lot.

However, I am going to post the code that i have used, as forums tend to occupy the higher results in Google and to make it a bit more easy finding for other new php programmers like me.

The coding was done in two pages:

1. `attempt.php` (this was the main page)
2. `level.php` (this page is called when the value of the first dropdown menu is changed)

jQuery and PHP have been used.

`attempt.php`:

```
<?php
//connect to the database
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","12345") or die("error ".mysql_error());

//connect to the trav table
mysql_select_db("trav",$con) or die("error ".mysql_error());
?>

<html>
<head>    
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
   $(function()
   {

        $(window).load(function()
        {
            $('#building').change(function()
            {
                var parentValue = $(this).val();


                // Determine the selected Value
                if( parentValue.length != "" )
                {
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: 'level.php',
                        data: {parent: parentValue},
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            $('#level').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#level').html('<option value="">Please Select</option>');
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">

    <table cellpadding="6" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Select Building : </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="building">
                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                    <?php
                        $query = "select * from build_list";
                        $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error'.mysql_error());

                        while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
                        {
                            echo '<option value="'. $row['building'] .'">' . ucwords($row['building']) . '</option>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Select Level : </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="level">
                        <option value="">Please Select</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>   
    </table></center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

`level.php`:

```
<?php
//connect to the database
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","12345") or die("error ".mysql_error());

//connect to the trav table
mysql_select_db("trav",$con) or die("error ".mysql_error());

$building = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['parent']);

$query = "select * from ";
$query = $query . $building;
$query = $query . ";";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error in Child Table!');

echo '<option value="">Please Select</option>';
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
{
    echo '<option value="'. $row['lvl'] .'">'.$row['lvl'].'</option>';
}
?>
```

**Note the above codes have been used from the blog of jogesh. The link has been mentioned above.**

Hope it helps other php programmers like me who are new to php but like to try our different things.