# Search results filtered by select/dropdown box

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a basic SQL query which grabs some data based on what is entered into a search field - I've put a select box which is populated from a column in the database - what I'd like to do is that when this is changed/post, it updates the results already found i.e. drills into them further by 'genre' of game.

Here's the code I already have

```
  echo "<select id='dropdown' name='dropdown' class='dropdown'>";//creates select HTML element
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT genre_name FROM genre'); //prepares sql query
    $stmt->execute(); //executes query
       while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { //fetches data in associative array
    echo "<option>{$row['genre_name']}</option>"; //inputs data found into select as an option
       }       
echo "</select>";




echo '<input type="submit" value="Filter" id="filter" name="filter" class="filter">';

if(!isset($_POST['filter']))//check if filter genre has been pressed
{
    echo ("<h4>Please select a genre</h4>"); //if not show this
}
    else { //otherwise if it has...do this
    echo ("<h4>Your results have been filtered</h4>");

    $dropvalue = $_POST['dropdown']; //sets variable of value of dropdown box
    $dbh = config();
            //sorting function, want to further drill search results by genre
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM consoles, games, genre WHERE genre.genre_name = :dropvalue");
            $stmt->bindValue(':dropvalue','%'.$dropvalue.'%');
            $stmt->execute();           
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<a href='details.php?game_id=".$row['game_id']."'>".$row['game_name']."</a>";
    echo "</ul>";
}
}
      $dbh = NULL; //terminates connection to database
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cascade Dropdown List using jQuery/PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137357/cascade-dropdown-list-using-jquery-php)

Comment: So what are you having a problem with? You don't ever really state a question.

Comment: The issue I am having is that having populated the drop down, how do I go about de-limiting the already returned data, further by the selection made by a user?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to do that. Just do :

1) Add `<form action="" method="post" id="drop_submit">` before `<select>` tag

2) Write `<select id="select_tag" name="YOUR_SELECT_NAME">` "OPTIONS BY PHP DB CODE" `</select>`

3) Add following javascript to submit your form anywhere in the HTML page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#status').change(function ()
  {
    $('#drop_submit').submit();
  });
</script>
```

Ya, Don't Forget to add,

```
if(isset($_POST['dropdown']))
{
  $dropdown = $_POST['dropdown'];
}
else
{
  $dropdown = "YOUR_DEFAULT / 1ST VALUE";
}
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT game_name FROM games WHERE games.game_id=('$dropdown')"); 
  //prepares sql statement, this prevents SQL Injection, as the query is sent seperate to the string entered.
  $stmt->bindValue(':dropdown','%'.$dropdown.'%');
  $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: is this possible without the use of JS?

Comment: PHP runs entirely at server side ! So if you want to control or manager user interaction you need client side programming ! Using js you would able to build highly dynamic web content. You can do it without js. For that you must create a submit button after the SELECT tag.. so user would be able to submit form with selected input. !

Comment: I've created another submit button that now should filter the results based on the value in the select box - However when I submit/post it appears no value is being passed from the dropdown - I posted the updated code in the original query. Thanks

Comment: @cstones88 : where's <form> tag ? you must add <select> and <input> tag between <form> tag add <form action="" method="post>

Answer (score 0):

As you update your question, it's solution for that

```
echo '<form action="" method="post">';

     echo "<select id='dropdown' name='dropdown' class='dropdown'>";//creates select HTML element
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT genre_name FROM genre'); //prepares sql query
        $stmt->execute(); //executes query
           while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { //fetches data in associative array
        echo "<option>{$row['genre_name']}</option>"; //inputs data found into select as an option
           }       
    echo "</select>";        
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Filter" id="filter" name="filter" class="filter">';

    echo '</form>';

    if(!isset($_POST['filter']))//check if filter genre has been pressed
    {
        echo ("<h4>Please select a genre</h4>"); //if not show this
    }
        else { //otherwise if it has...do this
        echo ("<h4>Your results have been filtered</h4>");

        $dropvalue = $_POST['dropdown']; //sets variable of value of dropdown box
        $dbh = config();
                //sorting function, want to further drill search results by genre
                $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM consoles, games, genre WHERE genre.genre_name = :dropvalue");
                $stmt->bindValue(':dropvalue','%'.$dropvalue.'%');
                $stmt->execute();           
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
    {
        echo "<ul>";
        echo "<a href='details.php?game_id=".$row['game_id']."'>".$row['game_name']."</a>";
        echo "</ul>";
    }
    }
          $dbh = NULL; //terminates connection to database
    ?>
```